# Hi i am new to python and this is my first project

Tags: python, udp, packet

I am trying send a data using a UDP protocol. I have the client send data that the server receives and then the server sends data back. I want to know how can I calculate the packet rate (packets per second).

```
name= (1 ,2,2,333333,33333,33333,3333,2222,2222,22222,2222,1) #data being sent
size=name.__sizeof__()

print(size) # we get the packet size
```

I hope by calculating the size we get to know the packets that are sent.

Please correct me if I am wrong. I am doing some self-study and have been stuck with this for a few days.

Comment: You can use `size = len(name)`

Comment: Quick Question: Does the buffer `name` get populated every second?

Comment: Like it depends on what I send. for example name=("kavya") in the first loop and in the second loop name("kavya", "Johnson") so what i want to know is the packet rate. I believe we can know the number of packet sent from getting the size of the variable "name" in each loop .Please correct me if i am wrong. B ut how can i know the packet sent in a second.

Comment: You can use the `time` module to calculate start-time and end-time. Through that you would know for x number of packets it takes y seconds. Simple math will give you packets/second

Comment: how can we find the number of packets send. By len() method or __sizeof()__ method.

Comment: len() queries for the number of items contained in a container. sys.getsizeof() on the other hand returns the memory size of the object:

You need to use `len` to get the number of packets received.

Comment: so by calculating the len() we would get the number of packet send / received. in-order to know the packet loss is it possible to know by calculating  the len() on both server and client side, and if the value (length ) is same no packet loss and if it varies packet  is lost .

Answer (score 0):

Tuples don’t have a get size method. Use the sys library and the getsizeof method like this.

```
import sys

name = (1 ,2,2,333333,33333,33333,3333,2222,2222,22222,2222,1)

size = sys.getsizeof(name)
```

Comment: Is that actually useful? It will give the size of a bunch of C pointers plus some refcounting info. It's not really related to what the tuple contains

Answer (score 0):

This is how the example function would look like: (Pseudo-Code)

Note: `len()` queries for the number of items contained in a container. `sys.getsizeof()` on the other hand returns the memory size of the object: You need to use `len` to get the number of packets received.

```
buffer = []
start_time = time.time()


# Call function populate buffer (or) insert relevant logic


time_elapsed = time.time() - start_time
print(f"Time Elapsed: {time_elapsed} seconds")
number_of_packets_per_second = len(buffer) // time_elapsed
print(f"Number of packets per second is: {number_of_packets_per_second}")
```

Ideally, recommend, putting all this into a `class` for clean code.

Comment: Thanks for your support. As I mentioned earlier, here the data is sent using UDP protocol. I would like to get some clarification on few things and get corrected if i am wrong. len() gives how many packets are transmitted /received. __sizeof__() gives the packet size. so here does the packet size already includes the header. if yes subtracting 8 byte from the packet size, will it result in payload size?